# Do finite linear combinations of sine functions always have infinitely many zeros?

Tags: functions, summation

To determine the sine-like function(ex: sound, electromagnetic wave), there are three factors: amplitude, freq and phase. While I study about composition of waves, I have one question - can we say that the composed wave has infinitely many '0-displacement points'? In formally, let the function $f(x)$ defined as below, while $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is the given constant.

> $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i \sin(b_i x + c_i)}$

To make clear statement, let's assume that sequence $\{a_i\}$ doesn't contain any 0. Also, $f(x)$ is not always zero - for example, if $\{a_i\} = \{2, 1, 1\}, \{b_i\} = \{1, 1, 1\}, \{ c_i \} = \{\pi, 0, 0\}$, $f(x) = 2\sin(x+\pi) + \sin(x) + \sin(x)=0$ always.

So my question is, does the function $f$ has infinitely many zeros, regardless to given sequence $\{a_i\}, \{b_i\}, \{c_i\}$ and $n$? If it is, how can I prove it with *mathmatical* way? I strongly believe that it has inf. many solutions because wave without 0-displacement is unnatural, but I want to prove it with formal way.

If not, then does it have at least *one* solution? Is there counterexamples?

Thank you for reading my long and not well-organized questions.

- Thank for TheSilverDoe, $b_i \neq 0$ for all $i = \{1, ..., n\}$

Comment: If $b_i = 0$ for all $i$, the function is constant and nonzero, so it has no zero.

Comment: sorry I forgot it - $b_i \neq 0$ for all n

Comment: Yes. Finite sums of sines are [almost periodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function) (periodic if $b_i$ are commensurable), so if they have a single zero they have infinitely many of them. Averaging such a sum, i.e. taking $\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac1{2T}\int_{-T}^T$, gives $0$ unless at least one of $b_i=0$, so they must take values of both signs, and hence must have at least one zero.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for the answer. However, I'm still have some questions in your explanation; How does each step of the statement can be verified? e.g. how can we say that the finite sums of sines are almost periodic? Could you give me a proof or some helpful references related to this topic?

Comment: A good introduction is [Cooke's paper Almost-Periodic Functions](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2321756) in AMM. He considers an example for the sum of two sines on p. 516.